# Is KeyError the appropriate Exception?

Tags: python, exception

I'm creating an open source project on Github and I want to make sure I do everything I can to make it robust, stable and that its Pythonic.  To this end, I have a question about what kind of exception I should use when I expect a key to exist in a dictionary and it is not included.

That is, the calling function would be something like:

```
def calling_func():
    my_dict = {
        'value_1': 1,
        'value_2': None,
        'value_3': '3',
    }

    foo(my_dict)
```

My function `foo` expects the dictionary to contain the `key` (and corresponding `value`), `value_4`.  Would it be appropriate to raise `KeyError` in the following case?

```
def foo(my_dict):
    expected_keys = ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4']

    for key in expected_keys:
        if key not in my_dict:
            raise KeyError
```

It seems the traditional use for `KeyError` is the inverse of this usage.

Should I create my own exception type for this?

```
class MissingKeyError(Exception):
    pass
```

Or something to this effect?

Comment: What gave you the impression `KeyError` is the inverse?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Actually, now that I think about it what I'm doing is logically equivalent to a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyError` is the appropriate exception.

When possible, use Python exceptions, especially for APIs suitable for 3rd parties. This saves on imports and learning curves.

You can simplify your code:

```
if not my_dict.viewkeys() >= set(expected_keys):
    raise KeyError
```

or simply access all the keys:

```
for key in expected_keys:
    my_dict[key]  # test for presence early
```

or *just not test* and let the code that does use the key raise the exception.

Comment: +1 to "just [don't] test and let the code that does use the key raise the exception"

Comment: Thank you for simplification.  This implementation is building a URL POST to a 3rd party API and will not handle the missing key - it just pukes.  :(